# Relation between graph geodesics and geodesics on a Riemannian metric

Tags: graph-theory, riemannian-geometry

I was wondering if there was a relationship between graph geodesics (shortest path) and geodesics on a Riemannian metric.

I am looking at high dimensional data embedded in a Riemannian metric. I can compute the geodesics between any two points by solving the nonlinear differential equations. However, I would prefer if I can approximate them using densely sampled data points.

Under what conditions is there a relationship between the two?

Comment: What do you mean by 'embedded in a Riemannian metric'? You can have a manifold with a Riemannian metric and then a geodesic is (locally) a shortest path between points.

Comment: I am thinking about data points $x_\alpha$ that represent Gibbs distributions: $x_k \propto \exp \left ( -\sum_a \lambda_{a} E_{ak} \right )$. The Fisher-Rao metric on the space of $\lambda$s defines a Riemannian metric. If I have many values of $\lambda$ corresponding to different distributions, I can compute the geodesic distance between any two using the Fisher Rao metric. I am wondering if I can approximate this by the graph geodesic on the graph formed by connecting k-nearest neighbors with each other with edge weights corresponding to the Euclidean distance between the points.